# How to submit the form to a servlet upon selecting an option from a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a `JSP` with the following form. I don't want any buttons associated with the form to submit.

```
<form name="difficulty" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/game.do" method="post">
    <div id="difficulty">
        <label>Difficulty Level</label><br>
        <select name="difficultyLevel" onselect="submitOption()">
            <option value="easy" name="easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="medium" name="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="hard" name="hard">Hard</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my `JS`:

```
function submitOption() {
    document.getElementsByName('difficulty').submit();
}
```

After selecting the option the user should see the result from the `servlet`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like the form will be submitted. What's the problem? Unless you have to use `forms['difficulty']` instead of `document.getEle...`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I changed it to forms['difficulty'].submit(); But no change.

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the JavaScript Console (Developer tools in Firefox and Chrome)?

Comment: Try giving an `id` to your `form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this (briefly) and was having some problems with the *onchange* callback (nothing happened). This however works great (register event with Js, not HTML attribute):

```
<form name="difficulty" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/game.do" method="post">
    <div id="difficulty">
        <label>Difficulty Level</label><br>
        <select name="difficultyLevel">
            <option value="easy" name="easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="medium" name="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="hard" name="hard">Hard</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName("difficultyLevel")[0].onchange = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('difficulty')[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem was about the proper JavaScript method for the `<select>`, which is `onchange`, not on `onselect`.

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByName)() returns an array. This should work:

```
function submitOption() {
    document.getElementsByName('difficulty')[0].submit();
}
```